# Ruby block - NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, syntax, block

Getting started with Rails and I'm stuck with a block operation. I want to loop through a model and update integer values for a new field by calculating difference between two datetime fields. Doing this in the console:

```
MyModel.all.each do |m|
  m.new_integer_field = m.existing_datetime_field - m.parent_object.existing_datetime_field
  m.save!
end
```

The result is

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `-' for nil:NilClass
```

It works on one record if I do:

```
m = MyModel.find(1)
m.new_integer_field = m.existing_datetime_field - m.parent_object.existing_datetime_field
m.save
```

I guess it's a basic syntax thing, but couldn't find obvious explanations. Grateful to get some pointers forward.

Comment: what is the output of `MyMethod.all.each {|i| puts i.existing_datetime_field.inspect }`? It seems one of these objects is `nil`, and this would explain why the `-` method is not defined.

Comment: That gives me a lot of dates but then a => nil at the end of the loop

Comment: No, you're right! There is a nil value in one of the instances!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The m.existing_datetime_field in one of the instances was nil and therefore the operation didn't work. You need to check for nil values if not sure:

```
MyModel.all.each do |m|
  unless m.existing_datetime_field == nil
    m.new_integer_field = m.existing_datetime_field - m.parent_object.existing_datetime_field
  m.save!
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As I already said probably one of the attributes of the instances are `nil`.

To check this use `#inspect` on the instances:

```
MyModel.all.each {|i| puts i.existing_datetime_field.inspect }
```

It seems one of these objects is `nil` and then the `-` method is not defined.

As you suggested you can check the operands before to calculate the differences.